# Localize script URL's based on the page subdomain

Tags: javascript, url, localization, greasemonkey

I'm new to Greasemonkey scripting and want to use the current URL to localize the links in the page or script.

For example, with a link like `http://en1.server.com/`, capture the `en1` part.

Currently the script uses:

```
// @include     /^http://en[0-9].forgeofempires.com/game/index.*$/
```

(Greasemonkey's regex @include syntax)

And below in the script there is:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://cdn.en.forgeofempires.com/swf/Preloader.swf?1358930484", "content", "100%", "100%", swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

But, if someone plays this game on a Hungarian, French or Swedish server, he must modify the script manually to be able to run the game properly under Linux.

I want to change the script to something like this:

```
// @include     /^http://*[0-9]\.server\.com/game/index.*$/
var url = window.location.href;
var loc = "remove everything but url prefixe"
swfobject.embedSWF("http://cdn.(+loc+).forgeofempires.com/swf/Preloader.swf?1358930484", "content", "100%", "100%", swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

But I don't know how to clean the URL and just keep the en, sw, it, fr or other localized prefix.

I'm trying to modify this script : https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/157358

Comment: Is the `swfobject.embedSWF` in the Greasemonkey script or is it in the target page's javascript?  If you are modifying an existing script, link to or paste-in that script.

Comment: I'm trying to modify this script : https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/157358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for updated question:

The key is to get just the hostname with `location.hostname` and then use a regex `replace` to extract the subdomain and strip any trailing digit.

So that script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Forge of Empires - Enable FoE to run with Adobe Flash 11.2
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org
// @description Forge of Empires, after the update on Jan 23rd 2013., requires that Adobe Flash Player V11.3 is installed on the system. This presents the problem mostly for Linux users, becouse only version 11.2 is available on Linux. This scripts enables game to run on Adobe Flash Player V11.2.
// @include     /^http://.+?\.forgeofempires\.com/game/index.*$/
// @grant       none
// @version     2
// ==/UserScript==

var swfVersionStr   = "11.2";
var baseHost        = location.hostname;
var subdomain       = baseHost.replace (/^(.+?)\d?\.forgeofempires\.com$/i, "$1");

swfobject.embedSWF (
    "http://cdn." + subdomain + ".forgeofempires.com/swf/Preloader.swf?1358930484", 
    "content", 
    "100%", "100%", 
    swfVersionStr, 
    xiSwfUrlStr, 
    flashvars, 
    params, 
    attributes
);
swfobject.addDomLoadEvent (createFullBrowserFlash);
```

Comment: `var subdomain   = baseHost.replace (/^(.+?)\d?\.server\.com$/i, "$1");`
Works partially, I always have en1 as subdomain :/

Comment: You did edit that line to match your server, right?  So it should be something like `var subdomain   = baseHost.replace (/^(.+?)\d?\.forgeofempires\.com$/i, "$1");` -- which works for me.

Comment: Yes it works ! I don't know why it didn't before…
Thank alot for your help ! :)